# Unity: Why Adding an Event Listener work only in Awake function?

Tags: c#, events, unity-game-engine, onclicklistener

I'd like to understand more about the following scenario. I have a simple base class that has a public variable of type Button. In my Start function, I use the Button's click event and add a listener to it. However, the code simply does not execute, and the only way it works is if the event listener is hooked in an Awake function as opposed to a Start function.

> Event does NOT execute in the following:

```
 protected virtual void OnExitedUI()
    {
        if(ExitedUI != null)
        { ExitedUI(this.gameObject); }
    }

    [Tooltip("The Button script/GameObject this UI uses as an Exit button. Used to destroy the UI and fire the exit event.")]
    public Button exitButton;

    // Subscribe to our events at the start.
    private void Start()
    {
        exitButton.onClick.AddListener(() => { OnExitClick(); });
    }

    // Event handler for the exit button click event.
    // Fire our ExitedUI event and destroy the object.
    private void OnExitClick()
    {
        Debug.Log("Exited UI!");
        OnExitedUI();
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
```

> Event executes and works as intended. Note the only thing that changed was Start to Awake.

```
 protected virtual void OnExitedUI()
    {
        if(ExitedUI != null)
        { ExitedUI(this.gameObject); }
    }

    [Tooltip("The Button script/GameObject this UI uses as an Exit button. Used to destroy the UI and fire the exit event.")]
    public Button exitButton;

    // Subscribe to our events at the start.
    private void Awake()
    {
        exitButton.onClick.AddListener(() => { OnExitClick(); });
    }

    // Event handler for the exit button click event.
    // Fire our ExitedUI event and destroy the object.
    private void OnExitClick()
    {
        Debug.Log("Exited UI!");
        OnExitedUI();
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
```

I am aware that the Awake function is called before the Start function. But I don't see how that affects the process - in fact, I would assume the Start methods should work better as I can be sure the Button is properly initialized or instantiated alongside this script.

Additional Note: The above script is the base of the UI manager class I am using for a UI GameObject that houses a set of panels and UI elements. One of the child panels include the Exit button referenced above.

Comment: I suspect that `Start` function is not even being called. Use `Debug.Log` to verify this.

Comment: Is your derived class also implementing Start()?  If so, it's your responsibility to call the base class's Start() method, too.  Unity is only going to call the most derived implementation of Start().  Additionally, you might consider not using inheritance at all, but composition (making your shared code its own script component).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In my Start function, I use the Button's click event and add a listener to it.

It is a key to your problem.

If you want to execute the listener's code, you will need to add the listener before executing the event. Otherwise delegate can't execute it, because it don't know anything about what it must execute.

When you add a listener and execute in `Start()`, you can't guarantee the adding will called first. Order of calling all same events like `Awake`, or `Start` not determined, and may change. But any `Awake` always call before any `Start`. So if you want execute event in `Start`, you must add listener in `Awake`.

Also, as Programmer said in a comment, `Start` is not always called. If the GameObject is disabled when the scene begins playing, `Start` will not be called until the object is enabled, but `Awake` will always be called.

Also, as PMV said in his comment, using `Start` in inherited class will prevent `Start` from being called in the base class. In this case you should get a warning about your method hiding an inherited method. If you did not get that warning, the problem is not here. Btw it's better to mark methods like `Start` and `Awake` as `virtual` in base class, and override it in inherited class, if you need to add some functionality.

Comment: His `Start()` and `Awake()` methods are marked *private* which excludes them from the IDE warning about hiding base class methods, but as Unity uses reflection voodoo to invoke these methods, the base class method is still being hidden. I *always* mark my Unity keyword methods as `public` because I know that they will be invoked externally and avoids this issue.

Comment: @Draco18s `protected` instead of `public` keeps your objects having a cleaner API service to other classes and you still get the benefits of derived classes being able to see it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain True enough.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot for the additional tips as well, especially the fact that I overlooked the Start method interaction in inherited classes.